# Grading a Patio in a Corner

Tags: patio, pavers, slope, grading

This is a follow-up question to this post:
[How would you grade this patio?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/52670/how-would-you-grade-this-patio/201686#201686)

What if instead of running a 1/32" per foot along the red lines (East to West) for the full run, I leveled off after 10 feet or so? The pitch along the blue lines (North to South) would stay as suggested for the full patio (1/8" per foot).

I've included a picture where the purple section would have "two directional" pitch (net pitch of NE to SW), and a cyan section where the pitch would only follow the Blue lines (North to South).

Are there any potential issues with this approach?  Thanks in advance.

[image: Patio Grading]

Comment: Why not follow the advice of the answer you accepted...

Comment: Not sure I follow.  The original post wasn’t mine.

Comment: If you don't maintain consistent grading in one direction, you will end up with a trip hazard where the purple meets the cyan.

Comment: Thanks @FreeMan , that’s a helpful consideration I hadn’t thought of.